# How to call postmessage in WKWebview to JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

Hi i want to ask so i have a problem in WKWebView IOS

So i want to post message to JS like this

```
 window.webkit.messageHandlers.postMessageListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}))
```

but nothing happened in JS

otherwise in android

```
"window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}))"
```

just like this and the JS Give response for this

Now i want to ask whats wrong with my script ?

sorry for bad english grammar

Answer (score 1):

For a simple explanation, you can check this article:

https://medium.com/@hoishing/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-64f94153ad0

If you want a more deep explanation, you can check this other article:

https://dev.to/gualtierofr/wkwebview-and-javascript-interaction-1pbl

In both they mention how **Triggering Javascript Functions from Swift**  AND **Receiving Javascript Messages**

Anyway, if you execute this function in JavaScript:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.postMessageListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}))
```

You must listening in Swift the name `postMessageListener` in this way:

Setup the WKWebView

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences

// Here I am guessing that the Frame of the WebView is the entire Screen
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)


configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "postMessageListener")
```

Conforming the Protocol `WKScriptMessageHandler`

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
   if message.name == "postMessageListener" {
       // Manage your Data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending Data from `WKWebview's` webpage to native code using `postMessage` handler,

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let   webCfg:WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        // Setup WKUserContentController instance for injecting user script
        var userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()

        // Add a script message handler for receiving  "buttonClicked" event notifications posted from the JS document using  window.webkit.messageHandlers.postMessageListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data})) script message
        userController.add(self, name: "nativeListener")
        // Configure the WKWebViewConfiguration instance with the WKUserContentController
        webCfg.userContentController = userController;

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), configuration: webCfg)
        return webView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let urlToLoad  = URL(string: "your_url_string")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        webView.load(URLRequest(url:urlToLoad!))
    }


    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
     if message.name == "nativeListener" {
          print(message.body) // prints the data that is sent from javascript
       }
    }
}
```