# How to communicate from embedded HTML to Swift to change bool

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, swiftui

Hello I would like to change the value of the binding variable 'click' once the onReady block in the html is executed. I can communicate from swift to html by using evaluate java script. But how do I communicate from the onReady in the html to swift to change the bools val? I tried making a coordinator class but

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var click: Bool        //variable to be changed
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        
        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = true;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function(event) {
                            //change here
                        },
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

**Update**

based on the article in the comments I have altered my code:

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var click: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

        userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "toggleMessageHandler")
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            if message.name == "toggleMessageHandler", let messageBody = message.body as? [String: Any] {
                if let messageValue = messageBody["message"] as? String, messageValue == "click now" {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.click = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = true;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function(event) {
                            if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler) {
                                window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler.postMessage({"message": "click now" });
                            }
                        },
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `WKScriptMessageHandler` is the only way, here's a tutorial: https://diamantidis.github.io/2020/02/02/two-way-communication-between-ios-wkwebview-and-web-page

Comment: @timbretimbre thanks, with all honesty I spent an hour trying to incorporate that example already. Im having some trouble doing so, I will add in my updated code. Maybe you can show how to get it squared away. But the example in the tutorial uses a class to define this, in my example SmartReelsView is a struct so I don't think I can take the exact same approach. Also do I have to add a new section in the html and put in a paragraph? Id appreciate your help.

Comment: @timbretimbre maybe you can look through me and VonC conversation below and rule out what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate from the embedded HTML to Swift to change a boolean value, you will need to make use of [`WKUserContentController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) and its delegate methods to listen to custom JavaScript events. You can use [`window.webkit.messageHandlers[handlerName].postMessage(message)` from `WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) in your JavaScript to send messages from JavaScript to Swift ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62035494/6309) for illustration).

The `SmartReelView` needs to create its own [`Coordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/coordinator) and conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler` to handle the JavaScript messages:

```swift
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var click: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Create user content controller
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        // Add the message handler script
        userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "toggleMessageHandler")
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            if message.name == "toggleMessageHandler", let messageBody = message.body as? [String: Any] {
                if let messageValue = messageBody["message"] as? String, messageValue == "click now" {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.click = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // existing loadInitialContent function
}
```

A `Coordinator` class is introduced that conforms to `WKScriptMessageHandler`. That will handle messages from JavaScript.
The Coordinator is added to the WebView as a script message handler under the name "toggleMessageHandler".
In your HTML's `onReady` JavaScript function, a message is posted to this script message handler. Swift's `userContentController(_:didReceive:)` then receives this message, processes it, and updates the `@Binding var click`.

That should allow the Swift code to react to events in the HTML, changing the `click` variable when the `onReady` event fires in JavaScript.

---

> It seems like the message is never received. Adding prints at the start of "`userContentController`" never run.

That could be from the ordering of operations or potentially a specific environment constraint that is not evident from the provided code. Given that prints inside the `userContentController` method are not showing up, this suggests that the method is never being called. That could be due to JavaScript not successfully sending the message, or because the message handler in Swift is not correctly set up.

Make sure the `WKUserContentController` and its message handlers are set *before* any web content is loaded. You are doing this correctly in your `makeUIView` function, but it is worth emphasizing.

And double-check your JavaScript actually executes the part that posts the message to `window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler`. You could add console logs to your JavaScript to see if it gets to that point.

You have set the `navigationDelegate` to your Coordinator, but make sure you also set the `WKScriptMessageHandler` by using `userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "toggleMessageHandler")`.

---

> The `onReady` block does execute for sure but the "`.postMessage({"message": "click now" });`" is never reached, meaning the `if` statements before it are evaluated to false. Removing the `if` statements still does not trigger the message. This means `window.webkit` is nil.
>
> I also tried running this on a real device and that did not help. The only other thing is a warning I get every time the video is played and paused which is: "`originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions`"

Make sure that `WKUserContentController` and the message handler have been set before loading the web content. The absence of this could lead to a null `window.webkit` object. And check whether the WebView is fully initialized when the `onReady` function is called. The `WKScriptMessageHandler` might not be fully set up at that point, and hence `window.webkit` may not be available.

You may try invoking `window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler.postMessage({"message": "click now"});` directly from Safari's Web Inspector console to manually check if the bridge between JavaScript and Swift works after the webpage is fully loaded. This will at least rule out any issues with the native code and narrow it down to the JavaScript side.

Warning messages regarding entitlements like `com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit` and `com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions` usually indicate that the app is trying to execute operations that require special permissions or entitlements. Although these warnings shouldn't necessarily impact the `WKScriptMessageHandler`, make sure you have all the necessary permissions in your [`Info.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list). See also [Where is `Info.plist` in Xcode 13](https://sarunw.com/posts/where-is-info-plist/).

---

> I think `WKUserContentController` is just not set up right. When I plug in my iPhone to and run the app, go to the YouTube video on my Mac and press on "Develop" then hover over my iPhone I don't see any web pages loaded. Taking a step back the only reason I want to change a bool value because if I do so I can listen for changes to the var and then in the `onChange` block I can set the `isPlaying` variable to true which will go back and unpause the video. This is all just so the video plays (`UNMUTED`) when it's ready. For some reason calling `watchPlayingState` from `onReady` doesn't work.
>
> I think the YouTube AGO goes through the js and makes sure the pause action is stimulated by a physical user action? How else would it know not to play the video. Calling `watchPlayingState` in the `onReady` doesn't work (but muting the vid right before does autoplay vid). But if I put a simple `onAppear` in my main view and toggle `isPlaying` then the video auto plays with sound (maybe API is tricked to think a user caused it). All the `onAppear` really does is make `watchPlayingState` run.

The behavior you are encountering may very well be due to the restrictions imposed by YouTube's API and browser security guidelines regarding autoplaying videos with sound. Videos will typically not autoplay with sound due to browser policies that restrict autoplay unless it is muted or triggered by a user action. That is to enhance the user experience and reduce unexpected video playbacks with sound. The YouTube API likely has similar restrictions. Even if you try to play the video using JavaScript in the `onReady` event, the API probably checks whether this request was due to a user action.

Given that you are not seeing any web pages loaded when inspecting your device, it does raise questions about whether the `WKUserContentController` and the JavaScript bridge are set up correctly. If the message handler is not added at the right time, it will not be available for JavaScript to call.

Your `onAppear` trick might work because SwiftUI sends this after the view has made its appearance, thereby possibly fooling the YouTube API into considering it as a user action.

If the goal is to autoplay the video with sound, you might not be able to achieve this without some user action, given the restrictions of web technologies and the YouTube API. However, the approach to use a Swift `@Binding` variable and `onChange` to detect when the video is ready to play is a reasonable one. You are essentially trying to create a handshake between the Swift code and the JavaScript code to coordinate the autoplay.

Make sure that the `WKUserContentController` and `WKScriptMessageHandler` are correctly set up; otherwise, the `window.webkit` object will not be available in the JavaScript context, and your Swift `@Binding` will not receive updates.

Comment: Thanks once again. I tried this code and it seems like the message is never received. Adding prints at the start of "userContentController" never run. I will add in my code on the update section. Maybe you can investigate further.

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to suggest some debugging avenues.

Comment: Thanks, the onReady block does execute for sure but the ".postMessage({"message": "click now" });" is never reached meaning the if statements before it are evaluated to false. Removing the if statements still does not trigger the message. This means window.webkit is nil. I also tried running this on a real device and that did not help. The only other thing is a warning I get every time the video is played and paused which is: "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions".

Comment: I think WKUserContentController is just not set up right. When I plug in my iPhone to and run the app, go to the YouTube video on my Mac and press on "Develop" then hover over my iPhone I don't see any web pages loaded. Taking a step back the only reason I want to change a bool value because if I do so I can listen for changes to the var and then in the onChange block I can set the isPlaying variable to true which will go back and unpause the video. This is all just so the video plays (UNMUTED) when it's ready. For some reason calling watchPlayingState from onReady doesn't work.

Comment: I think the YouTube api go through the js and makes sure the pause action is stimulated by a physical user action? how else would it know not to play the video. Calling watchPlayingState in the onReady doesn't work (but muting the vid right before does autoplay vid). But if I put a simple onAppear in my main view and toggle isPlaying then the video auto plays with sound (maybe api is tricked to think a user caused it). All the onAppear really does is make watchPlayingState run.

Comment: I moved the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002708/swift-wkusercontentcontroller-and-wkscriptmessagehandler-are-not-set-up-right since WKScriptMessageHandler not being set up right isn't directly related to the original question.

Comment: von if you can fix it I will bounty the question and give you all 167 of my points. I spent 3 hours trying.

Comment: @ahmed Please keep your points. I will try later on today.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using WKScriptMessageHandler to pass data from the html to swift you can call a function in the embed html that throws and error which is caught by a completion handler in swift. The error object thrown can contain any data needed. Here's an example:

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
let link: String
@Binding var isPlaying: Bool
@Binding var click: Bool
@Binding var totalLength: Double
@Binding var currentTime: Double

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    
    webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

    loadInitialContent(in: webView)
    
    return webView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let jsString = """
            isPlaying = \((isPlaying || click) ? "true" : "false");
            watchPlayingState();
            seekToTime(\(currentTime));
        """
    uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var parent: SmartReelView

    init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("getLength()", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                let string = "\(error)"
                do {
                    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "Video duration: (\\d+)", options: [])
                    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)) {
                        if let range = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string) {
                            let videoDuration = string[range]
                            self.parent.totalLength = Double(videoDuration) ?? 0.0
                        }
                    }
                } catch { print("") }
            }
        })
    }
}

private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
    let embedHTML = """
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .iframe-container iframe {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var isPlaying = true;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                width: '100%',
                videoId: '\(link)',
                playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': function(event) {
                        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                            player.seekTo(0);
                            player.playVideo();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        
        function watchPlayingState() {
            if (isPlaying) {
                player.playVideo();
            } else {
                player.pauseVideo();
            }
        }
    
        function sendCurrentTime() {
            const currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
        }
    
        function seekToTime(seconds) {
            if (player && seconds > 0.0) {
                player.seekTo(seconds);
                timeToSeek = 0.0;
            }
        }

        function getLength() {
            var length = player.getDuration();
            var errorMessage = "Video duration: " + length;
            throw new Error(errorMessage);
        }
    </script>
    """
    
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
}
```

}