# Making tabview vertical shifts view to the right

Tags: swift, swiftui, layout, youtube

I have made a vertical scrolling tab view by rotating the tab view and the inner views. In doing so the view appears shifted around 10.5 points to the right (more or less on bigger and smaller devices). I can simply add in an offset to move the view 10.5 points to the right but this doesn't look good across all devices.

Showing the view alone without any tabviews looks good. It's just after I put the views inside the vertical tabView that it looks shifted right. Id appreciate some insight into a more efficient method to center it instead of a basic offset modifier. You can ignore all the code other than what's in AllVideoView.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var selected = ""
    @State private var arr = ["-q6-DxWZnlQ", "Bp3iu47RRJQ", "lXJdgDjw1Ks", "It3ecCpuzgc", "7WNJjr8QM1w"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
            TabView(selection: $selected){
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id).tag(id)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true), height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            }
            //.offset(x: -10.5)       // this makes it align right 
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false), height: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
            viewIsShowing = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var viewIsShowing: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var jsString = """
                isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
                watchPlayingState();
            """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            if self.parent.viewIsShowing {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function clickReady() {
                player.playVideo();
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: When creating a horizontal scroll, I usually uses ScrollView(.horizontal) / with a HStack / then ForEach on my data to display my views.

Comment: @OneCommentMan This is not a scroll view and it is not horizontal. This is a vertical tabView that allows up and down swipes to change through tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have rotated the `TabView` and the views inside it to create a vertically scrolling tab, it is possible the rotation might result in some spatial adjustments that could shift the views. That shifting is what you are experiencing as a 10.5-point move to the right.

To make your vertical `TabView` consistent across different screen sizes, consider the following alternatives:

Use [`GeometryReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) to obtain dimensions of the parent view. You can then calculate the offset dynamically to ensure it is centered.

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
    TabView(selection: $selected) {
        // your code
    }
    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
    .offset(x: -(geometry.size.width - geometry.size.height) / 2)
}
```

See also "[How to use Geometry Reader in SwiftUI](https://www.swiftanytime.com/blog/geometry-reader-in-swiftui#basic-implementation)" for illustration.

Also, make sure the frames for both the inner view and the rotated `TabView` are defined in a way that leaves no room for such shifting. Double-check that you are defining the frame after rotation and not before.

---

You could use [`.alignmentGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignment) to adjust the horizontal alignment of the inner view based on the dimensions of the `TabView`.

Assuming you want to move the view based on some calculated offset (`calculatedOffset`).

First, you would define an `HorizontalAlignment`:

```swift
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum MyAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }

    static let myAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(MyAlignment.self)
}
```

Then, you can apply this custom alignment guide to your `TabView` like so:

```swift
TabView(selection: $selected) {
    // Your existing code
}
.rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
.alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment) { d in
    // calculatedOffset would be the value you have determined you need to move your view by
    let calculatedOffset: CGFloat = 10.5  // replace this with your calculated value
    return d[HorizontalAlignment.center] - calculatedOffset
}
```

Finally, you would need to ensure that your `ZStack` uses this custom alignment to position the `TabView`:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .myAlignment, vertical: .center)) {
    // your existing code, including the TabView
}
```

I have used a hard-coded `calculatedOffset` value of 10.5 just as a placeholder. But you can replace this with any value you calculate dynamically to adjust your view's position as needed.

By using alignment guides, you can achieve very fine-grained control over the layout of your views. That may help you fix the issue you are experiencing.

---

As an alternative approach, you could wrap the `TabView` inside another view, then manipulate the position of the `TabView` within that container. That allows for more control over its placement.

```swift
HStack {
    Spacer()
    TabView(selection: $selected){
        // your code
    }
    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
    Spacer()
}
```

Or create a custom SwiftUI modifier that encapsulates the rotation and translation logic, making it easier to maintain and apply across different views.

The idea is to dynamically adapt the view layout based on the actual dimensions, thereby eliminating hard-coded values that are not adaptable across different screen sizes.

Comment: Is this possible or can multiple web views be loaded at the same time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026312/load-next-youtube-video-before-being-displayed-swift-ui

Comment: Von maybe take a look at this if you have the time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049571/drag-gesture-causes-sim-to-crash-swift-ui