# Load next YouTube video before being displayed swift ui

Tags: html, swiftui, youtube

I'm making a TikTok clone using YouTube shorts. I have everything working properly but I'm running into some unwanted behavior where the next video takes a few seconds to render and load in when it appears. I would like to figure out a way to load the next video while the currently displayed video is playing so that it is ready when it appears. I'm not sure how to accomplish this type of behavior. I'd appreciate some pointers.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var selected = ""
    @State private var arr = ["-q6-DxWZnlQ", "Bp3iu47RRJQ", "lXJdgDjw1Ks", "It3ecCpuzgc", "7WNJjr8QM1w"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
            TabView(selection: $selected){
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id).tag(id)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true), height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            }
            .offset(x: -10.5) 
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false), height: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
            viewIsShowing = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var viewIsShowing: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var jsString = """
                isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
                watchPlayingState();
            """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            if self.parent.viewIsShowing {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function clickReady() {
                player.playVideo();
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would have been a caching mechanism that loads the next video's data in advance so that it can be instantly played when the user switches to it. But a [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) is not designed for preloading YouTube videos.

You might instead load the next WebView in a hidden state and pause its video. When the user moves to this video, you can then resume playback. That might not guarantee an instantaneous start, especially with slower internet connections.

One way to implement that is to make the `SingleVideoView` capable of starting in a paused state:

```swift
struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying: Bool
    
    // add an initializer to set the initial playing state
    init(link: String, isInitiallyPlaying: Bool = true) {
        self.link = link
        self._isVideoPlaying = State(initialValue: isInitiallyPlaying)
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Now, when creating your `TabView`, you can set the initial playing state as `false` for all but the first video:

```swift
TabView(selection: $selected){
    ForEach(arr.indices, id: \.self){ index in
        SingleVideoView(link: arr[index], isInitiallyPlaying: index == 0).tag(arr[index])
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

When you switch between tabs, you can programmatically set `isVideoPlaying` to `true` for the next video, but this will require you to manage the state more carefully across your views.

Warning: that technique involves creating multiple `WKWebView` instances, which could have memory implications based on the number of videos you preload.

---

> I would like to understand more as to what makes "`func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {`" trigger?
> Is it the view just appearing onto the screen?
> Because I don't think the `isVideoPlaying` variable is responsible for that, it is only responsible for mimicking a fake press to unpause the video since the web view already auto renders the video in a paused ready state.

The [`func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/makeuiview(context:)) method is part of SwiftUI's [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) protocol. That method is responsible for creating the underlying `UIView` (in your case, a `WKWebView`) that your SwiftUI view wraps. It is invoked when the SwiftUI system determines that the view needs to be rendered on the screen. Essentially, it is the initial setup call for your `UIView`.

In a SwiftUI lifecycle:

1. `makeUIView` is called first to create the initial `UIView`.
2. `updateUIView` is called any time the SwiftUI view's state or properties change, to reflect those changes in the underlying `UIView`.

The method `makeUIView` is not directly related to whether a video starts playing; it is merely responsible for initializing the `WKWebView` with appropriate configurations. Your `WKWebView` will follow its own lifecycle for content loading and rendering based on its settings and JavaScript logic.

Thus, `makeUIView` triggers when SwiftUI determines it needs to render the underlying `WKWebView`, which typically happens when this view is about to appear on-screen, but its triggering is not influenced by the `isVideoPlaying` variable.

---

> The video loading that I referred to is the process of makeUIView, and if "which typically happens when this view is about to appear on-screen", then how would changing the value of isVideoPlaying create another instance of WKWebView for the next video?

The function `makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView` will be invoked when a new instance of the `UIViewRepresentable` SwiftUI view is created and rendered on the screen. In your specific case, it happens as part of the `ForEach` loop inside the `TabView` where you are iterating over the `arr` array:

```swift
ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
    SingleVideoView(link: id).tag(id)
}
```

Each time a `SingleVideoView` is instantiated with a new `id`, it will trigger the `makeUIView` method, creating a new `WKWebView` instance with the video identified by that `id`.

Changing the value of `isVideoPlaying` does not directly trigger the creation of a new `WKWebView` instance. The purpose of the `isVideoPlaying` state variable seems to be only for toggling the play/pause state of the video within the `WKWebView` via JavaScript. As noted above, that variable does not influence the lifecycle of the SwiftUI view or the underlying `WKWebView`.

To preload the next video while the current one is playing, you would have to manage this manually.

One way to achieve this could be to pre-instantiate the next `SingleVideoView` in the background while the current one is playing, but that could involve complex state management and might be resource-intensive.

Another way would be to use some form of caching or predictive loading within the `WKWebView` itself, although this could require intricate JavaScript and may not be fully controllable from the SwiftUI context.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Id like to understand more as to what makes "func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {" trigger? Is it the view just appearing onto the screen? because I don't think the isVideoPlaying variable is responsible for that, it is only responsible for mimicking a fake press to unpause the video since the web view already auto renders the video in a paused ready state.

Comment: The video loading that I referred to is the process of makeUIView and if "which typically happens when this view is about to appear on-screen" then how would changing the value of isVideoPlaying create another instance of WKWebView for the next video?

Comment: Thanks a lot your explanation inspired some fixes. A little off topic but as I scroll through I can scroll back to the previous video and when I do so the video is still rendered in the state it was left in and even plays at the same duration It was left at. As much as I would like to keep this I think this is causing my phone to overheat. As you mentioned having multiple web view instances uses a lot of recourses. How can I destroy these instances after the user scroll past them?

Comment: @ahmed I was afraid that would be the case. Could you describe in a new question your current code, in order to address that issue properly (by me or others)

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031329/too-many-web-view-instances-causes-phone-to-overheat-swift