# Too many web view instances causes phone to overheat Swift

Tags: html, swift, swiftui, webview, wkwebview

I am making a TikTok clone using YouTube shorts. I present videos in a vertical tabview that allows users to scroll though a list of videos. Since these videos are on the web I use a webview to render them in. As the user scrolls through the tabview new instances of web views are created for the new videos. When the user scrolls backwards they can see the previous videos (already rendered) at the same duration.

This means that the web views are not destroyed when the user swipes away from them. After scrolling for a few minutes the device gets noticeably warm due to the fact that a lot of web view instances require a large sum of resources. How can I destroy these web views when the user is 2 videos beyond?

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var selected = ""


    @State private var arr = ["-q6-DxWZnlQ", "Bp3iu47RRJQ", "lXJdgDjw1Ks", "It3ecCpuzgc", "7WNJjr8QM1w", "z2t0W8YSzZo", "w8RBGoH_6BM", "DJNAUBoxW5g", "Gv0X34FZ_8M", "EUTsaD1JFZE",
    "yM9iLvOL2v4", "lnqhfn2n-Jo", "qkUpWwUAFPA", "Uz21KTMGwAI", "682rP7VrMUI",
    "4AOcYT6tnsE", "DEz9ngMqVT0", "VOY2MviU5ig", "F8DvoxgP77M", "LGiRWOawMiw",
    "Ub8j6l35VEM", "0xEQbJxR2hw", "SVow553Lluc", "0cPTM7v0vlw", "G12vO9ziK0k"]


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
            TabView(selection: $selected){
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id).tag(id)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true), height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            }
            .offset(x: -10.5) 
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false), height: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
            viewIsShowing = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var viewIsShowing: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var jsString = """
                isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
                watchPlayingState();
            """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            if self.parent.viewIsShowing {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function clickReady() {
                player.playVideo();
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    @State private var destroy = false

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VideoModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, destroy: $destroy)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            if viewModel.selected == link {
                isVideoPlaying = true
                destroy = false
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.selected, perform: { _ in
            if viewModel.selected != link {
                isVideoPlaying = false
                
                if let x = viewModel.VideosToShow.firstIndex(where: { $0.videoID == viewModel.selected }), let j = viewModel.VideosToShow.firstIndex(where: { $0.videoID == link }){
                    if (x - j) > 2 && !destroy {
                        destroy = true
                        print("destroy \(j)")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var destroy: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }
    
    func createView(context: Context) { //copy of makeUIView but doesnt return a webview
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController
        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
        if destroy && uiView.navigationDelegate != nil {
            destroyWebView(uiView)
        } else if uiView.navigationDelegate == nil {
            createView(context: context)
        }
        
        //rest of code
    }
    
    private func destroyWebView(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        print("destroyed")
        webView.navigationDelegate = nil
        webView.stopLoading()
        webView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            //rest of code
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
            //unchanged
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To optimize, you might consider a view recycling mechanism (a "view pool") so that web view instances are reused instead of creating new instances each time a new video is to be displayed.

However, since you are specifically asking how to destroy web views when the user is 2 videos beyond, you could implement logic to manually deallocate these web views and clear their content.

To manually destroy a `WKWebView`, you would need to:

- Remove the web view from its superview if it has one.
- Set its `navigationDelegate` and [`UIDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415009-uidelegate) to `nil`.
- Call the [`stopLoading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414981-stoploading) method on it.
- Set the web view itself to `nil` (this is generally handled by ARC if there are no strong references left to the web view).

First, add a flag in `SmartReelView` to check if a web view is active:

```swift
@Binding var isActive: Bool
```

Update the `updateUIView` and `makeUIView` methods to consider the active state:

```swift
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    // existing code
    if isActive {
        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
    }
    return webView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    if isActive {
        // existing code
    } else {
        destroyWebView(uiView)
    }
}

private func destroyWebView(_ webView: WKWebView) {
    webView.navigationDelegate = nil
    webView.stopLoading()
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Then, in `SingleVideoView`, introduce logic to update the `isActive` binding based on how far the user has scrolled. You might need to pass an index and calculate if the view is within 2 videos of the currently active one:

```swift
struct SingleVideoView: View {
    // existing properties
    @Binding var activeIndex: Int // The index of the currently active (visible) video
    let index: Int  // The index of this particular video

    var body: some View {
        // existing code

        SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing, isActive: .constant(shouldActivate))
    }

    private var shouldActivate: Bool {
        return abs(activeIndex - index) <= 2
    }
}
```

In `AllVideoView`, maintain the state for the currently active video index:

```swift
@State private var activeIndex = 0
```

Pass this index to each `SingleVideoView`:

```swift
ForEach(arr.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    SingleVideoView(link: arr[index], activeIndex: $activeIndex, index: index)
}
```

Finally, update the `activeIndex` whenever the `TabView`'s selection changes.

These changes should limit the number of web views in memory to only those that are within 2 videos of the currently active one, which should mitigate the resource issue.

> Changing the value of the isActive in SingleVideoView doesn't always trigger the updateUiView, especially if the view isn't on the screen. If I put a print inside the onChange in the view then this print will run every time the video is 2 indexes away. But adding a print in the destroyWebView doesn't always run. This means that the `updateUiView` func may not check for changes if the view isn't displayed. If I scroll 2 videos away then scroll back to the video then "deleted" is printed.
>
> Is there a way to hold the instance SmartReelView from SingleVideoView and call the destroyWebView directly to make sure it runs?

`updateUIView` not being called consistently should be due to SwiftUI's optimization; it does not update the views that are not currently on the screen. Since you are working with a `TabView`, SwiftUI tries to be efficient by not updating the invisible tabs.

Directly holding a SwiftUI `View` is not recommended due to SwiftUI's declarative nature. Since manipulating SwiftUI's managed state (`@Published`, `@State`) within the update cycle of a `UIViewRepresentable` can lead to undefined behavior or errors, a different approach would be to encapsulate the `WKWebView` management logic within a dedicated class that can be observed by SwiftUI. That avoids altering `@Published` or `@State` variables within the update cycle.

Create a dedicated WebViewManager class that can be observed:

```swift
class WebViewManager: ObservableObject {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    var link: String
    
    init(link: String) {
        self.link = link
        createWebView()
    }
    
    func createWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        // additional setup logic here
    }
    
    func destroyWebView() {
        self.webView?.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
        self.webView = nil
    }
}
```

Modify `SmartReelView` and `SingleVideoView` to use this `WebViewManager`:

```swift
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webViewManager: WebViewManager

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return webViewManager.webView ?? WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if webViewManager.webView == nil {
            webViewManager.createWebView()
        }
        // additional logic to load or reload the content
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var isActive = true
    @ObservedObject var webViewManager: WebViewManager

    var body: some View {
        SmartReelView(webViewManager: webViewManager)
            .onAppear {
                isActive = true
                if webViewManager.webView == nil {
                    webViewManager.createWebView()
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                isActive = false
                webViewManager.destroyWebView()
            }
    }
}
```

Modify the `ForEach` loop to create a `WebViewManager` for each `SingleVideoView`:

```swift
ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { id in
    SingleVideoView(link: id, webViewManager: WebViewManager(link: id))
    .tag(id)
}
```

That way, the `WebViewManager` handles the creation and destruction of `WKWebView` instances. The `SmartReelView` and `SingleVideoView` observe this manager and react accordingly, without directly modifying the `@State` or `@Published` variables within the update cycle.

---

I would still consider instead a pool of `WKWebView` instances, which involves maintaining a collection of reusable views, handing them out when needed, and returning them to the pool when they are no longer in use.

A simplified example (focusing on the WebView pool) would include first a `WebViewPool` Manager.
That manager will handle the logic for pooling:

```swift
class WebViewPool {
    private var pool: [WKWebView] = []
    
    func getWebView() -> WKWebView {
        if let webView = pool.first {
            pool.removeFirst()
            return webView
        } else {
            // Create a new web view, configure it as needed
            let webView = WKWebView()
            return webView
        }
    }
    
    func returnWebView(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        // Optionally clear the webView content
        webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
        
        pool.append(webView)
    }
}
```

You can then create an instance of this manager in your SwiftUI View where the web views are needed, for example in `AllVideoView`.

```swift
struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var webViewPool = WebViewPool()
    //... existing code
}
```

And in the `SingleVideoView` or `SmartReelView`, you can use the pool to get a web view when the view appears and return it when it disappears.

```swift
struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @Binding var webViewPool: WebViewPool
    //... existing code
    
    var body: some View {
        // existing code
        SmartReelView(link: link, webViewPool: $webViewPool)
            .onAppear {
                // Check out a WebView when appearing
            }
            .onDisappear {
                // Return WebView when disappearing
            }
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var webViewPool: WebViewPool
    var webView: WKWebView?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView = webViewPool.getWebView()
        // existing code
        return webView!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        // existing code
    }
    
    func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, coordinator: Coordinator) {
        webViewPool.returnWebView(uiView)
    }
}
```

That does not cover all edge cases. And managing the lifecycle (check out and return) of web views needs to be more nuanced. Depending on your needs, you might check out a web view not only when the view appears, but also when a new video needs to be loaded.

Still, the idea remains: by reusing the web views this way, you would minimize the overhead of creating and destroying web view instances, which should improve the performance of your application.

Comment: Trying the first approach: Changing the value of the isActive in SingleVideoView doesn't always trigger the updateUiView, especially if the view isn't on the screen. If I put a print inside the onChange in the view then this print will run every time the video is 2 indexes away. But adding a print in the  destroyWebView doesn't always run. This means that the updateUiView func may not check for changes if the view isn't displayed. If I scroll 2 videos away then scroll back to the video then "deleted" is printed.

Comment: Is there a way to hold the instance SmartReelView from SingleVideoView and call the destroyWebView directly to make sure it runs?

Comment: Also Im facing another issue where videos that have had their webViews destroyed do not reload or render if the user goes back to them. I created a function to recreate the view if the web view is nill and I call it in the updateUiView but it doesn't fix the issue. I added all my updated code above. Id appreciate some tips.

Comment: Thanks everything looks good. But storing a variable web view as a Published variable or even a State variable in the view doesn't work since you are changing its value as the view updates. This gives me a purple error.

Comment: @ahmed OK. I have revised and replace the previous edit with one which avoids altering `@Published` or `@State` variables within the update cycle.