# Drag Gesture causes sim to crash Swift UI

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I am trying to implement a drag gesture on a drop down view to close it. When I execute the drag gesture upwards the view moves for a bit then freezes and the whole simulator freezes then Xcode crashes.

When I try this exact same code on a card swipe view for example it works. Why does it not work in this situation?

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessagesHomeView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    @State var showNotifications: Bool = false
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    showNotifications.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "bell").font(.title)
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            VStack {
                if showNotifications {
                    ZStack {
                        Color(UIColor.darkGray)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("Notifications").font(.title3).foregroundColor(.white)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(10).padding(.top, 70)
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).frame(width: 90, height: 9).foregroundColor(.white)
                                .gesture (
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { gesture in
                                            if gesture.translation.height < 0 {
                                                offset = gesture.translation
                                            }
                                        }.onEnded { _ in
                                            withAnimation{
                                                modifyState()
                                            }
                                        }

                                )
                        }.padding(.bottom, 4)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 500)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
                    .cornerRadius(10, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight])
                    .offset(y: offset.height)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    func modifyState(){
        switch offset.height {
        case -600...(-100):
            withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                showNotifications = false
            }
            offset = .zero
        default:
            withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                offset = .zero
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DragGesture` is applied to a part of the view (the `RoundedRectangle`), but the offset is being applied to the whole container with that part (the `ZStack`). This doesn't work.

Try applying the drag gesture to the `ZStack` instead, after the `.offset` modifier:

```swift
ZStack {
    Color(UIColor.darkGray)
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
        Text("Notifications").font(.title3).foregroundColor(.white)
        Spacer()
    }.padding(10).padding(.top, 70)
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).frame(width: 90, height: 9).foregroundColor(.white)
    }.padding(.bottom, 4)
}
.frame(height: 500)
.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
.cornerRadius(10, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight])
.offset(y: offset.height)
.gesture (
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { gesture in
            if gesture.translation.height < 0 {
                offset = gesture.translation
            }
        }.onEnded { _ in
            withAnimation{
                modifyState()
            }
        }
)
Spacer()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot maybe you would know this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120804/swift-ui-left-edge-swipe-to-exit-view